# Adding functions in search index of loudant

Tags: search, indexing, couchdb, cloudant

I have a Json document in cloudant as:

```
{
  "_id": "3-f812228f45b5f4e4962505561953ew245",
  "_rev": "3-f812228f45b5f4e496250556195372b2",
  "wiki_page": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_lion",
  "name": "african lion",
  "class": "mammal",
  "diet": "herbivore"
}
```

I want to make a search index that can search this document when I input queries as "afrian lion" or "lion african",...

I make a function that can return all cases of permutation in "doc.name" for indexing (This function works well and it also had been checked in pure JS environment). However, it does't work in cloudant, the output return **null** when i input a query.

This is a code that I made in search index:

```
function(doc){
  var list = [];
  function permute(ss, used, res, level, list){
    if(level==ss.length&&res!==""){
        list.push(res);
        return;
    }
    for(var i=0; i<ss.length; i++){
    console.log("loops");
        if (used[i]===true){
          continue;
        }

        if(level>=0){
          if (res!="" && list.indexOf(res)<0){
              list.push(res.trim());
          }

          used[i]=true;
          permute(ss, used, res+" "+ss[i], level+1, list)
          used[i]=false;
        }
      }
  }
  function permuteword(s){
      var ss=s.split(" ");
      var used = [];
    var res = "";
    list = [];
    permute(ss, used, res, 0, list);
    console.log(list);
  }

  var contentIndex=[];
  contentIndex=permuteword("african lion");
  for(var i=0; i<contentIndex.length; i++){
    index("default", contentIndex[i]);
  }
}
```

How can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Your update looks good, but there is still one issue: you are not returning the list from the `permuteword` function. I believe you also need to remove calls to `console.log`. Once I did these two things I was able to get it to work with Cloudant using the following search queries (I also changed your hard-coded call with "african lion" back to doc.name):

```
default:"african"
default:"african lion"
default:"lion"
default:"lion african"
```

Here is the final script:

```
function(doc){
  var list = [];
  function permute(ss, used, res, level, list){
    if(level==ss.length&&res!==""){
        list.push(res);
        return;
    }
    for(var i=0; i<ss.length; i++){
        if (used[i]===true){
          continue;
        }

        if(level>=0){
          if (res!="" && list.indexOf(res)<0){
              list.push(res.trim());
          }

          used[i]=true;
          permute(ss, used, res+" "+ss[i], level+1, list)
          used[i]=false;
        }
      }
  }
  function permuteword(s){
    var ss=s.split(" ");
    var used = [];
    var res = "";
    list = [];
    permute(ss, used, res, 0, list);
    return list;
  }

  if (doc.name) {
    var contentIndex=permuteword(doc.name);
    for(var i=0; i<contentIndex.length; i++){
      index("default", contentIndex[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Updated JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/14e7L3gw/1/

**Original Answer**

I believe there are issues with your Javascript. The `permuteword` function is not returning any results. See this JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/14e7L3gw/

Note: I added some logging and commented out the call to index. Run with your browser debugger to see the output.

Here is what is happening:

1. The first call to `permuteword` calls `permute(["african","lion"], [], "", 0, []);`
2. The first `if` in `permuteword` fails because `level` (0) != `ss.length()` (2) and `res` == "".
3. Then the function loops through `ss`, but never does anything because `level` = 0.
4. Ultimately `permuteword` returns an empty array, so nothing gets indexed.

Comment: I have just edited the codes by replacing return in permuteword as list by global variable. The code works at https://jsfiddle.net/bnb53qyd/2/ .But it still doesn't work in cloudant.