# Access specified attributes of Json for search index in cloudant

Tags: json, search, indexing, cloudant

I have a Json document as:

```
{
  "_id": "3de00db35e6549604c711e7295a1982a",
  "_rev": "1-ecba71644d341dfe5cb9abf6dd13b23a",
  "dateCreated": "2014-01-29 00:00:00",
  "attributeCollection": {
    "attributeArray": [
      {
        "updateable": false,
        "lookup": "issuetype",
        "issueAttributeDefinitionId": 13,
        "attributeType": 1,
        "name": "Web Type",
        "value": [
          "Improper Limitation of Authentication"
        ]
      },
      {
        "updateable": true,
        "lookup": "status",
        "issueAttributeDefinitionId": 1,
        "attributeType": 4,
        "name": "Status",
        "value": [
          "Access with Right Permission"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "hash": "287030d6efa085b5b92b7106c0edb6d7"
}
```

I want to create search index for document using "name" and "value" ("name" or "value" only). I accessed these attributes by this codes:

```
for (var i=0; i<doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray.length; i++) {
    if (doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].name) {
        name = doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].name;
    }
    if (doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value) {
        value = doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value;
    }
}
```

It works when i use `contentindex = name + " "+ value`; the content shows `"Web Type Improper Limitation of Authentication"`. However, if i use value only `contentindex = value`, it doesn't work, it shows null.

I know that the structure of "value" likes array (array with 1 element) and it doesn't have any attribute name.

How can i access the value properly?

**Update:**

When i index some cases as:

**1. It works**

`var content=name + " " + value;
index("default", content);`

**2. It works**

`index("default", name);`

**3. It doesn't work**

`index("default", value);`

4.I fixed with by revised the code to get "value" as:

```
     if (doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value) {

     for (var j=0; j<doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value.length; j++){
       value = doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value[j];
       } 
     }
```

Or

```
 if (doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value) {
      value = doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value[0];
 }
```

It works with `index("default", value);`

However, when i used permutation function as discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929753/adding-functions-in-search-index-of-loudant/36940512#36940512)

**5. It works**

```
var content= permuteword(name);
    for(var k=0; k<content.length; k++){
         index("default", content[k], { store : true });
    }
```

**6. It doesn't work**

```
var content= permuteword(value);
    for(var k=0; k<content.length; k++){
         index("default", content[k], { store : true });
    }
```

**7. It doesn't work**

```
var content=name + " " +value;
var content1= permuteword(content);
    for(var k=0; k<content1.length; k++){
         index("default", content1[k], { store : true });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure I completely understand your question. It sounds like you are creating an index like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray.length; i++) {
    if (doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].name) {
        name = doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].name;
    }
    if (doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value) {
        value = doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value;
    }
    index("contentindex", name + " " + value);
}
```

If this is the case you could try indexing the name and value separately (**Update**: changed to access each element in the value array):

```
for (var i=0; i<doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray.length; i++) {
    if (doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].name) {
        name = doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].name;
        index("contentindex", name);
    }
    if (doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value) {
        for (var j=0; j<doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value.length; j++) {
            value = doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value[j];
            index("contentindex", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then querying by either the name or the value should return the correct result.

Please let me know if I am misunderstanding you question.

Comment: The "value" is returned in string but why it doesn't work in case 6 and 7.

Comment: Is "value" always a string? It probably won't work when it's an array - which is what it will be if you set it to doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value. Are you having issues when you use the value in the array and not the array itself?

Comment: I updated my response to index each element in the value array. I'm not sure if that's your issue.

Comment: It is not my issue. Your update looks like my case no. 4. Actually, I want to get "value" in a string and call a permuteword function. The permuateword can work with "name" but it doesn't work with "value" or "name + value". So I think the problem in the return of "value". Could you please take a look in cases 5, 6 and 7.

Comment: How could I convert "value" to string?

Comment: You can use Array.join to turn an array into a string. This would turn your value array into a string separated by spaces: `value = doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value.join(' ')`

Comment: I have tried, but "value" still does not work with the function discussed in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929753/adding-functions-in-search-index-of-loudant/36940512#36940512. "name" works well.

Comment: #MarkWatson Could you try "value" for the function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929753/adding-functions-in-search-index-of-loudant/36940512#36940512