# Convert element of array to String when extracting in Json by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I have a Json document as:

```
{
  "_id": "13fee4aad95c7f822c0b559bd8d09fb0",
  "_rev": "5-336dea3680af3e7ec0de29369be90b09",
  "attributeCollection": {
    "attributeArray": [
      {
          "name": "Web Issue",
          "value": [
          "web security authentication"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "hash": "1047fe2e1e58e5c8246b26f015d0ecd7"
}
```

**I already extracted "value" by JS with this code:**

```
if (doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value) {
        for (var j=0; j<doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value.length; j++) {
            value = doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value[j];
        }
}
```

**My problem is how to convert "value" to string**. Because "value" just has 1 element, i used some ways as:

- `var content=value.toString();`

or

- `var content=value.join("");`

Even I use loop as:

```
var content="";
for(var i; i<value.length; i++){
   content=content+value[i];
}
```

It still doesn't work, what is the problem in these cases.

Comment: the "value" is extracted successfully from Json, it already returned an array. The problem is how to convert element ""web security authentication" to string.

Comment: this value is already in string. why you need to convert again?

Comment: It is not a string, because when i call a function with string parameter. It can not recognize "value" is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your **i**?? I have replace **i** with **0** and its working fine.

```
  var value=[];
  var doc={
    "_id": "13fee4aad95c7f822c0b559bd8d09fb0",
    "_rev": "5-336dea3680af3e7ec0de29369be90b09",
    "attributeCollection": {
      "attributeArray": [
        {
          "value": [
            "web security authentication"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "hash": "1047fe2e1e58e5c8246b26f015d0ecd7"
  };

  if (doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[0].value) {
          for (var j=0; j<doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[0].value.length; j++) {
              value.push(doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[0].value[j]);
          }
  }

 console.log(value.join(""));
```

Comment: You printed out an array, not a string.

Comment: @NguyenChiHieu I have improve my answer. please check.

Comment: the problem which i mentioned is how to convert array "value" to string after extracting from Json. Your solution I already mentioned in the topic. It doesn't work.

Comment: do you have any jsfiddle? this is working fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jitendratiwari/aag9d8e3/1/)

Comment: as I mentioned alert and console.log printed "value" as array. I checked in a function with string parameter input. It doesn't work with "value".

Comment: #JitendaraTiwari Could you try "value" for the input parameter in this function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929753/adding-functions-in-search-index-of-loudant/36940512#36940512. It works with "name", but fail with "value" even i did many above ways.

Comment: Yes it work with "value". may be your project have some global variable with name "value".

Comment: #JitendaraTiwari I run JS in cloudant, maybe cloudant has some limitations. Have you ever tried something with cloudant?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`
    var doc={
        "_id": "13fee4aad95c7f822c0b559bd8d09fb0",
        "_rev": "5-336dea3680af3e7ec0de29369be90b09",
        "attributeCollection": {
            "attributeArray": [{
                "value": [
                    "web security authentication"
                ]
            }]
        },
        "hash": "1047fe2e1e58e5c8246b26f015d0ecd7"
    };

```
var value=[];

if(doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray.length>0){
    for(var i=0;i<doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray.length;i++){
        value.push(doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value);
    }
}

value=value.join("\n");
console.log(value);
```

`

Comment: It still doesn't work, I use a function with string parameter. It can not recognize   "value" as a string.

Comment: If doc is string -- you can use `doc=JSON.parse(doc);` and use this code

Comment: Yeah, obtaining "value" from Json is already done, I already got "value" but converting the "value" to pure string is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem happens on integer elements. So tried this:

```
value = value + "";
```

Note: cloudant has trouble indexing empty string. So before calling index on anything, make sure it is never an empty string, or the search will fail on that document without telling you why (index will pass as successful, but it will not work)